# How do i configure angular-cli & webpack to create source maps for debugging

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, source-maps

This subject which should be trivial turned out to be a mess for me.
I have am angular-cli project, and trying to configure webpack to create source maps, d.ts files and polyfill files. first things first, tried to configure source maps. I did **ng eject** and have the config file. what do I need to configure in the config file to create source maps?

Tried looking for an answer online... nothing really relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to fix this.
In an angular-cli project the webpack config is hidden until an **ng eject** command that spits out the webpack.config file.
The webpack config file does not use the regular **devTools** property rather the **plugins** property where it creates an instance of **SourceMapDevToolPlugin** passing it 4 parameters **filename, moduleFilenameTemplate, fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate, sourceRoot**, removing all parameters except **filename** and changing its value to **"[name].js.map"** resolved this issue, and now for each bundle file a map.js file is created.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you currectly all you need to is add this line to your webpack.config

```
devtool: 'source-map'
```

Comment: when doing **ng eject** to control the webpack config it uses the **plugins**  property instead of the **devtool** property